# LocationManager.getSingleUpdate() not performing any callback - why?

Tags: android

So this code worked on friday:

```
    public void requestLocationUpdate() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(SINGLE_LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION);
        PendingIntent singleUpdatePI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        IntentFilter locIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(SINGLE_LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION);
        SingleUpdateReceiver receiver = new SingleUpdateReceiver(); 
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, locIntentFilter);
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, singleUpdatePI);  
    }

    class SingleUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {      
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // ... never invoked
        }
    }
```

Today, `onReceive()` simply will not be invoked. Is there any reason why this shouldn't work today? The only thing changed is that I'm on a different WiFi router now.

I can see a couple of suspicious lines in LogCat:

```
06-23 15:10:36.540     709-7716/? D/LocationManagerService﹕ request 430483d8 fused Request[ACCURACY_BLOCK fused requested=+10m0s0ms fastest=+10m0s0ms num=1] from com.nilzor.app(10195)
06-23 15:10:36.540     709-7716/? D/LocationManagerService﹕ provider request: fused ProviderRequest[ON interval=+10m0s0ms]
```

...don't know if that is relevant?

The documentation of `requestSingleUpdate` points me to [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), which again tells me that it might take a while to get the first update. Is that true also for `requestSingleUpdate`? On friday, the callback fired within a second of the request. Today I've tried 10+ times and it havent fired once. 5 minutes counting as I post now.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to wi-fi you get coordinates from your router. It does not matter where you are located, in your wi-fi area/place use real gps, or gps spoiler.